# setting NTP server on Windows machine using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We want to use Windows PowerShell to set an particular NTP server on Windows 7 workstations that are not attached to a domain. The goal is to have a number of scripts run to standardize/speed up/simplify the initial setup of non-domain workstations.

We have tried:

```
Push-Location
Set-Location HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters
Set-ItemProperty . NtpServer "ca.pool.ntp.org"
Pop-Location
```

And this script:

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:ca.pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual /update
Stop-Service w32time
Start-Service w32time
```

After running both scripts (with admin priv), we check the Registry and find NtpServer at: HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters has been updated to "ca.pool.ntp.org" but looking in Control Panel > Date and Time we find the old NTP server is still listed -- even if the computer is restarted.

*this is the code which was developed from Graham Gold's response below and works:*

```
Push-Location
Set-Location HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers
Set-ItemProperty . 0 "ca.pool.ntp.org"
Set-ItemProperty . "(Default)" "0"
Set-Location HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters
Set-ItemProperty . NtpServer "ca.pool.ntp.org"
Pop-Location
Stop-Service w32time
Start-Service w32time
```

**Note:** This script overwrites whatever is currently in the parameter "0". To use properly, you should have your script make your NTP server the next sequential entry.

Comment: What is the response to `w32tm /query /status` on a machine where either of these scripts has been run?

Comment: Hi Graham, it reported: 
"The following error occurred: The service has not been started. (0x80070426)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a bit of googling about w32tm vs control panel date/time, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509928/how-can-i-update-the-date-and-time-control-panel-to-match-the-w32time-service-co), which appears to be what you need.

Hope that helps you out :-)

Answer (score 0):

From ntppool.org:
*If you're using a recent Windows version, you can use the ntp client that is built into the system. As administrator enter*

```
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org 3.pool.ntp.org"
```

https://www.ntppool.org/en/use.html